# How to load all the certificates in a PEM-encoded certificate chain?

Tags: python, openssl, ssl-certificate, x509certificate, pyopenssl

When I use `OpenSSL.crypto.load_certificate(b'< PEM encoded certificate bytes >')` function on a PEM encoded full certificate chain, only the first certificate is loaded as a `OpenSSL.crypto.X509` object.

The remaining certificates are completely ignored. I assume this is because the parser hits "END CERTIFICATE" and stop reading. Is there a utility function in OpenSSL (or elsewhere) which parses and loads the entire certificate chain?

By a "full certificate chain" I mean a PEM formatted certificate containing multiple `----- BEGIN CERTIFICATE -----` / `----- END CERTIFICATE -----` markers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a short snippet that reads all certificates from a PEM-encoded byte buffer:

```
start_line = b'-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----'

def read_all_certs(pem_bytes):
    result = []
    cert_slots = pem_bytes.split(start_line)
    for single_pem_cert in cert_slots[1:]:
        cert = OpenSSL.crypto.load_certificate(OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, start_line+single_pem_cert)
        result.append(cert)
    return result
```

Answer (score 7):

This answer won't be fully applicable until the next [`cryptography`](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/) release (39), but you can now do this with `cryptography.x509.load_pem_x509_certificates`:

```py
from cryptography import x509

certs = x509.load_pem_x509_certificates(b"...")
```

That API will return a list of one or more certificates in the input, or it'll raise an exception if no valid certificate PEMs are present.